# How to write a SQL query to calculate percentages based on values across different tables?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

Suppose I have a database containing two tables, similar to below:

```
Table 1:

tweet_id  tweet
1         Scrap the election results
2         The election was great!
3         Great stuff

Table 2:

politician  tweet_id
TRUE        1
FALSE       2
FALSE       3
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query which returns the percentage of tweets that contain the word `'election'` broken down by whether they were a politician or not.

So for instance here, the first 2 tweets in `Table 1` contain the word `election`. By looking at `Table 2`, you can see that `tweet_id` 1 was written by a `politician`, whereas `tweet_id` 2 was written by a `non-politician`.

Hence, the result of the SQL query should return 50% for politicians and 50% for non-politicians (i.e. two tweets contained the word 'election', one by a politician and one by a non-politician).

Any ideas how to write this in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating one subquery to return all election tweets, and one subquery to return all election tweets by politicians, then join.

Here is a sample. Note that you may need to cast the totals to decimals before dividing (depending on which SQL provider you are working in).

```
select 
    politician_tweets.total / election_tweets.total
from
(
select
  count(tweet) as total
from
  table_1
  join table_2 on table_1.tweet_id = table_2.tweet_id
where
  tweet like '%election%'
) election_tweets

join
(
select
  count(tweet) as total
from
  table_1
  join table_2 on table_1.tweet_id = table_2.tweet_id
where
  tweet like '%election%' and
  politician = 1
) politician_tweets
on 1 = 1
```

Comment: For some reason this returns 0. Any ideas why?

Comment: Absolutely-it’s dividing an integer by an integer, and so it’s returning an integer. You have to convert them to decimals before dividing. What sql provider are you using? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? PostgreSQL? (This can affect the proper convert/cast syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select t2.politician, avg( case when t.tweet like '%election%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as election_ratio
from tweets t join
     table2 t2
     on t.tweet_id = t2.tweet_id
group by t2.politician;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b62e98dc06890de322b649edad02fe79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the solution doesn't fully work. It returns 3% for politicians and 3% for users. Whereas, it should produce results that add to 100% since it's to do with the proportion of politicians and non-politicians that tweeted something with word 'election'. Any ideas?

Comment: @HelpMe . . . It works.  I added a db<>fiddle to illustrate on your sample data.